# MOSI signal losing bandwidth in SPI communication

Tags: spi, clock, signal-processing, signal-integrity, protocol

I am testing the SPI MOSI signal for signal integrity. The length of the PCB trace is 207 mm. Unfortunately, the signal is curved at the rising edge of the cycle. The frequency is 1Mhz. I think it is due to the trace capacitance but how to remedy the situation?[image]

Comment: Hm, it's also asymmetrical, affecting rising edges only. It's also not very periodic, though that need not be a problem as such. There are unlimited possible explanations; you could greatly reduce this number by providing additional information: what is the schematic? Layout? What is the pin configuration? Source code?

Comment: Sorry I will change the heading, it is the MOSI pin, the trace is 207 mm, this is SPIA, the trace is sandwiched between three other traces. The probe is a passive 300 V, 1 ghz bandwidth.

Comment: There is no description between which ICs the bus is wired to check the ICs, no schematics to check for errors, no code to check for errors. Is the bus even supposed to be 1.8V IO levels?

Comment: @LifeshackRadio Out of curiosity, where did you get that probe? I've never seen 1 GHz passive probes that aren't transmission line probes.

Comment: @Hearth It is the tektronix passive probe TPP series.